# Dishwasher won't stop filling with hot water

Tags: dishwasher

I have a Kitchenaid dishwasher (model: KUDE40FXSS5)

Our kitchen faucet and drain frozen a couple of days ago. The dishwasher ran that night, without taking in any water. I ran a space heater, etc. and got the water from the faucet running again. But, the dishwasher now constantly runs hot water from the ‘water inlet opening’ (as the manual for the dishwasher calls it).

The searches I’ve done seem to indicate that the water inlet valve is damaged, and needs to be replaced. But, I wanted to post and see if anyone had an alternative suggestion before I get someone out to replace the valve. One other note. The hot water runs into the dishwasher whether the dishwasher is powered on, or off.

I've posted 3 photos of the dishwasher (exterior, wide shot interior and close up interior, with a red arrow marking the water inlet opening) Thanks in advance for any thoughts, or advice!

best
Walt

[image][image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely sounds like the inlet valve is stuck open or otherwise damaged.

It may need to be replaced, depending on exactly what was damaged.

To turn the water off, follow the water line from the dishwasher, there should be a valve where it attaches to the house plumbing, this will stop the water.  Depending on how it is plumbed it may also shutoff water to the kitchen sink as these water lines are often combined.

The inlet valve is usually right next to where the supply water hose connects on the underside of the dishwasher.

A repair technician could repair it, or an online search with your model number will find you replacement parts and instructions on how to replace it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I'll remove the inlet valve and see if it looks like it's repairable, otherwise I'll order the new part. Thanks again. best Walt